# REACT EDITED. trigger function from another component : TypeError: refreshmap is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I would like to reload the page when the date is picked. I have a prop called refreshmap.

I am a newbie in react.

i want to trigger the function ("refreshmap") when an onChange when the date change :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
import MapLeaflet2 from './MapLeaflet2';


class Picker extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  }



  onChange = (date,refreshmap) => this.setState({date},
    function(){

      const DateContext =this.state.date;
      refreshmap()


    })

  render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <DateTimePicker
          onChange={(date) => this.onChange(date, this.refreshmap)} 
          value={this.state.date}
        />
         <MapLeaflet2 date = {this.state.date.toString()}/>


         )}         
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Picker;
```

Here i get this error :

> TypeError: refreshmap is not a function

As an exemple I use it for a button here. It works well.

```
import React from 'react';
import mapButtonStyles from './mapButtonStyles';

const RefreshButton = ({ refreshmap}) => (
  <button
    type="button"
    style={mapButtonStyles}
    className="map-button"
    onClick={refreshmap}
  >
    <i className="fas fa-sync-alt fa-2x" />
  </button>
);

export default RefreshButton;
```

It is working perfectly with the button component **but NOT with the Picker. I get the error message TypeError: refreshmap is not a function**

As mentionned, i am a newbie, so any suggestions or observation would be greatly valued !

Comment: You should pass `refreshmap` function to `RefreshButton` component as a prop

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to call `refreshmap` function in `onChange` event of `DateTimePicker`. If so, then

```
onChange={(date) => this.onChange(date, this.props.refreshmap)}
```

And catch the reference of `refreshmap` in `onChange` and call accordingly.

```
onChange = (date, refreshmap) => this.setState({date},
    function(){
      const DateContext =this.state.date;
      refreshmap();
})
```

If I misunderstood the question, let me know.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunatly, nothing is triggered. It says that refreshmap is declared but never used" when catching the reference of refreshmap

Comment: Yes, that's because you didn't call it. See the statement in my answer `And catch the reference of refreshmap in onChange and call accordingly`. Anyways, I have modified the answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't know why, but it says that refreshmap() is not a function. I will edit my question

Comment: Updated answer. Look for onChange event code. if it is still undefined, that mostly you are not passing it correctly as props. Share the code that is using component `Picker `.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just trigger you refreshmap function in your onChange function :

```
onChange = date => this.setState({date},
function(){
  const DateContext =this.state.date;
  this.props.refreshmap();
})
```

with :

```
<DateTimePicker
      onChange={this.onChange}
      value={this.state.date}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunatly, it says that refreshmap is not a function

Comment: Did you pass refreshmap to your Picker component props?

Comment: i tried to pass it this way, but did not manage |   constructor() {
               super();
              this.refreshStationsList = this.refreshStationsList.bind(this);
             }

Comment: did you call your Picker component like this ? :
<Picker refreshmap={refreshmap / this.refreshmap / this.props.refreshmap} ... />
like you called RefreshButton component:
<RefreshButton refreshmap={...} ... /> ?

It seems to me that you dont have this function in yourPicker component.
And do they have the same parent component ?